# tt_news category image url

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I need the url of the image from tt_news category to fill conf.tt_news.10.stdWrap.ifEmpty. Does anyone have an idea. My approach

```
lib.catimage = TEXT
lib.catimage {
  table = tt_news_cat
  select {
    pidInList = 2
    andWhere {
      data = GPVar:tx_ttnews|cat
      ....????

page.headerData {
  15 = RECORDS
  15 {
    source.data = GPvar:tx_ttnews|tt_news
    tables = tt_news
    conf.tt_news = COA
    conf.tt_news.10 = IMG_RESOURCE
    conf.tt_news.10.file {
      width = 403
      import = uploads/pics/
      import.field = image
      import.listNum = 0
    }
    conf.tt_news.10.stdWrap.ifEmpty < lib.catimage
    wrap = <link rel="image_src" href="{$BaseUrl}|" />
  }
}
```

I have a new approach, but do not see the error. If I take out the commented brace the path is correct but the syntax of the script is incorrect. The first part also does not work anymore. Here the modified version.

```
    page.headerData {
      15 = RECORDS
      15 {
       source.data = GPvar:tx_ttnews|tt_news
       tables = tt_news
       conf.tt_news = COA
       conf.tt_news.10 = IMG_RESOURCE
       conf.tt_news.10.file {
         width = 403
         import = uploads/pics/
         import.field = image
         import.listNum = 0
       }
       conf.tt_news.10.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = CONTENT
       conf.tt_news.10.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
         table = tt_news_cat
         select {
           selectFields = image
           pidInList = 2
           languageField = sys_language_uid
           where = deleted=0 AND hidden=0
           andWhere {
             data = GPvar:tx_ttnews|category
             wrap = uid=|
             intval = 1
           }
         }
      #}
      renderObj = TEXT
      renderObj.field = image
    }
    wrap = <link rel="image_src" href="{$BaseUrl}|" />
  }
}
```